# How to render a Lit element component in a Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, web-component, nuxtjs3, lit

I'm encountering difficulties when integrating Lit elements into a Nuxt project, particularly with server-side rendering (SSR). My Lit component renders correctly when the site is rendered client-side (by setting `ssr: false` in `nuxt.config`), but I face issues when using the default SSR mode. The error message I receive is: "HTMLElement is not defined." I understand the root cause of this issue and have attempted various solutions, but none have been successful.

I've explored the following resources and methods:

- The GitHub repository [nuxt-ssr-lit](https://github.com/prashantpalikhe/nuxt-ssr-lit), which is a Nuxt3 module designed for server-side rendering and client-side hydration of Lit custom elements.
- A workaround that involves defining `HTMLElement` globally: `global.HTMLElement = typeof window === 'undefined' ? Object : window.HTMLElement;`.

Despite consulting various AI platforms, none of the solutions provided have resolved my issue. I'm hoping a human perspective might offer a different approach or insight.

Thanks in advance!

Sidenote:
I don't really care if the Lit component has to built or not prior to using it in a Nuxt project. The component itself does not have to be server side rendered either, as long as can render it in a Nuxt project.

Comment: Lit has node condition exports that should already alleviate that `HTMLElement is not defined` problem. You might be using components with a production/browser build of Lit bundled in.